# Can we import one table twice from PowerBI

Tags: import, powerbi

I want to import one table twice from PowerBI?
I have join two times with a single table. Hence as a workaround,  is it possible to import table.csv into powerBI two times with different names? Please let me know whether any elegant solution in this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely import one table multiple times by duplicating the source power query or else you can join in separate queries to keep your source table intact.